# QWidget or just paintings?

Tags: html, qt4, widget

I work on a Qt4 calendar custom widget and in month view (a grid of more or less 30 cells/days), in each day's cell, I want to draw events of the day like this:

**start hour** - title
**start hour** - title
**start hour** - title
(...)

So, just a vertical list of events, with HTML formatting.

I'd like to offer the possibility to move events betweens cells with drag'n'drop.
So, I don't know if I must create a QWidget for each cell with QLabels inside or if I can render html on those cells and manage drag'n'drop in a other way...

Comment: Read about QGraphicsView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to, you could manage drag and drop yourself by checking which item was clicked on when the drag started, and putting the appropriate data into the drag events.  However, I think your first option sounds easier, at least until you come across other requirements that makes it not work.